# How to parse the scxml file using NSXMLParser

Tags: iphone, ios5, ios6, nsxmlparser

I have the following scxml file

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<scxml version="1.0" name="statemachine" initial="initialState" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/scxml" binding="early" exmode="lax">

<state id="initialState">
    <transition target="state1" cond="TRUEPREDICATE" />
</state>
<state id="state1">
    <transition target="state2" cond="SELF.currentStateName == 'state1'" />
</state>
<state id="state2">
    <transition target="state1" cond="SELF.currentStateName == 'state2' && SELF.count <  5" />
    <transition target="finalState" cond="SELF.currentStateName == 'state2' && SELF.count >=  5" />
</state>
<state id="finalState"/>
</scxml>
```

I want to parse this file using NSXMLParser. My thought when I click the button, we want check the state and target.
I want to display the current state value.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The whole document will be in **Dictionary** format. Inside this Dictionary, **state** will be one dictionary with key id AND **transition** is another dictionary with keys target, cond. In `-didStartElement`, you can get these values.*

Guess, this would work for you!!